# Open-source, PHP, DB-free SCM for brochure site?

Tags: php, cms

A friend of mine is an architect starting her own business, and needs to build a basic brochure site to promote herself. The site will simply include a few articles and pictures of projects she worked on.

There are so many CMS that it's hard to choose on, but the following are basic requirements:
- Open-source
- Mature, and with good support
- In PHP, since just about any hoster supports PHP
- DB-free, to make deployment really basic. If the SCM really does need a database for indexing, SQLite is OK
- Good UI so she can easily add articles and photos to her site without having to know any HTML/CSS
- Nice templates to choose from

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WordPress.  It's written in PHP, offers CMS features, and has a large ecosystem of themes and plugins.  See the list of [recommended WordPress hosts](http://wordpress.org/hosting/).

For SCM, most good hosts will support Subversion, Git, or both.

Comment: Thanks. Ideally, I'd rather a lighter tool than WordPress, but I'll see how the install goes.

Comment: It's one of the lighter-weight CMS that I've used.  You can also check out Drupal, Joomla, or Movable Type.

Comment: But it's not "DB-free", as asked (no?)

Comment: Actually, since contents won't change much, I guess there's an easier way to do it: Does someone know of a script that takes a template and simply turns basic HTML pages + JPG into complete static HTML, ready to be uploaded to any web site?